# Flask добавляет HTML символы

Tags: python, flask

Я недавно начал программировать на Flask.
Задача: требуется передать содержимое json файла из python в javascript. Я сделал шаблон HTML страницы с тегом

```
<script>
    let data_api = {{ apidata }};
</script>
```

Но в переменную записывается следующая строка:

```
{&#39;data&#39;: {&#39;archive&#39;: &#39;archive.csv&#39;, &#39;now&#39;: &#39;data.json&#39;}};
```

Пробовал сначала преобразовать в словарь, а затем передать, но результат тот же.

Возможно ли это исправить?

Comment: Это защита от XSS-атак.

Comment: @andreymal, возможно ли это как-то обойти?

Comment: Обходить не надо, иначе, возможно, найдётся способ что-нибудь взломать. А вот правильно экранировать json-объект стоит https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#standard-filters

Comment: Или на худой конец вручную обезопасить json-строку вот этими заменами https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/e69b49bd3d2df261316c1c5dbdd53b96d93d2f56/src/flask/json/__init__.py#L237-L239